# How to output all categories and sub-categories in a hierarchical form from categories table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a categories table with columns `id, name, level, parent_id`. I have a product category like .. Jewellery and watches > Jewellery > Ear-rings.

My categories look like

```
id, name, level, parent_id
1, Jewellery and watches, L1, null
2, Jewellery, L2, 1,
3, Ear-rings, L3, 2
```

How do I write a query that will give me the following output

```
id, name, displayName
1, Jewellery and watches, Jewellery and watches
2, Jewellery, Jewellery and watches > Jewellery
3, Ear-rings, Jewellery and watches > Jewellery > Ear-rings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive query.

```
with recursive top_down as (
    select id, parent_id, name, name as display_name
    from categories
    where parent_id is null
union all
    select t.id, t.parent_id, t.name, concat(display_name, ' > ', t.name)
    from categories t
    join top_down r on t.parent_id = r.id
)
select id, name, display_name
from top_down;

 id |         name          |                 display_name                  
----+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | Jewellery and watches | Jewellery and watches
  2 | Jewellery             | Jewellery and watches > Jewellery
  3 | Ear-rings             | Jewellery and watches > Jewellery > Ear-rings
(3 rows)
```

Note, that the column `level` is basically redundant.